# My Django form is not displaying on the HTML template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

This is the code for the form, model, and template. That refused to show.

this is the forms.py code

```
    from voterRegistration.models import voterReg
    from django import forms
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import voterReg
    
    
    class VoterRegForm(ModelForm):
        firstname = forms.CharField(initial='First Name', max_length=20)
        lastname = forms.CharField(initial='Last Name', max_length=30)
        email = forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter your Email Address')
        phonenumber = forms.IntegerField()
        Address = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
        gender = forms.CheckboxInput()
        dateofbirth = forms.DateField()
        state = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        local = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        occupation = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        passport = forms.ImageField()
    
        class Meta:
            model = voterReg            
            fields = ("firstname", "lastname","email", "phonenumber", "Address", "gender", "dateofbirth", "state", "local", "occupation", "passport")
    
        def save(self, commit=True):
            voterReg = super(VoterRegForm, self).save(commit=False)
            voterReg.firstname = self.cleaned_data["firstname"]
            voterReg.lastname = self.cleaned_data["lastname"]
            voterReg.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
            voterReg.phonenumber = self.cleaned_data["phone number"]
            voterReg.Address = self.cleaned_data["Address"]
            voterReg.gender = self.cleaned_data["gender"]
            voterReg.dateofbirth = self.cleaned_data["dateofbirth"]
            voterReg.state = self.cleaned_data["state"]
            voterReg.local = self.cleaned_data["local"]
            voterReg.occupation = self.cleaned_data["occupation"]
            voterReg.passport = self.cleaned_data["passport"]
    
            if commit:
                voterReg.save()
            return voterReg
```

this is the voterRegistration html template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; shrink-to-fit=no;">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
            <title>e-NEC || Voter Registration page</title>
    
            <!--load static-->
            {% load static %}
    
            <!--link to bootstrap and the rest-->
            <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{% static 'css/stylez.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{% static 'fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
            
        </head>
    
        <body style="background-color:azure">
    
            <!-- navbar fixed-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light " style="background-color: green;">
                <p style=" text-align: center; font-size: bold; color: white;" class="navbar-brand">e-NEC VOTER REGISTRATION PAGE</p>
            </nav>
        
            <!--load crispy form tags-->
            {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
        
            <div class="signup-form">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <h1>Voter Registration Form</h1>
                    <!-- very important for csrf token, security validation-->
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p|crispy}}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        
        
            <footer>
                <div class="container-fluid padding">
                    <div class="col-12">
                              <hr class="light-100">
                            <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">&copy; 2021 Independent National Electoral Commission</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        
        <script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
    
    </html>
```

this is the model.py code

```
    from django.db import models
    
 
    
    class voterReg(models.Model):
        firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        email = models.EmailField()
        phonenumber = models.BigIntegerField()
        Address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        dateofbirth = models.DateField()
        state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        local = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I ran this and it didn't display on my html template page, i have tried out solutions and to no avail too.

Comment: please attach your views,py file

Comment: Please post ```views.py``` as well.

Comment: you're doing `form.as_p|crispy` instead of `form | crispy` or `{% crispy form %}`. Why is that so? crispy expects a form instance but if you're passing as_p this would produce html and crispy template tag / filter would most likely break, thus rendering empty output.